# SQL Stored Procedure Combine UNION rows into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would love to know how to put the results of this query into one row instead of 3 rows it gives back:

```
SELECT COUNT([fms].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) FROM [fms].[dbo].[Booking]
INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[Container] ON [fms].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fms].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[File] ON [fms].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fms].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
WHERE [fms].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fms].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT([fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) FROM [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking]
INNER JOIN [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container] ON [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
INNER JOIN [fmsAir].[dbo].[File] ON [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fmsAir].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
WHERE [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fmsAir].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'

UNION ALL

SELECT COUNT([fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) FROM [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking]
INNER JOIN [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container] ON [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
INNER JOIN [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File] ON [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
WHERE [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
```

Is there a way that I can combine the 3 result rows and count them into 1 row. I am using this inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to SUM all the count of all 3 SELECT queries, You could you this:

```
SELECT SUM(cnt)
FROM(
   SELECT COUNT([fms].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) cnt
   FROM [fms].[dbo].[Booking]
   INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[Container] ON [fms].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fms].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
   INNER JOIN [fms].[dbo].[File] ON [fms].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fms].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
   WHERE [fms].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fms].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT([fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) 
   FROM [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking]
   INNER JOIN [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container] ON [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
   INNER JOIN [fmsAir].[dbo].[File] ON [fmsAir].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fmsAir].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
   WHERE [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fmsAir].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT([fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER) 
   FROM [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking]
   INNER JOIN [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container] ON [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].[BOOKINGNUMBER] = [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container].[BOOKINGNUMBER]
   INNER JOIN [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File] ON [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Container].FILENUMBER = [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File].FILENUMBER
   WHERE [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
) AS tmp;
```

Comment: @Zeina OP say "combine the 3 result rows and **count them into 1 row**". May be I misunderstood OP's intention, may be not.

Comment: The cnt in SUM gives me an error. It wants a column name, but there are 3 column names i need to sum

Comment: I edited @PhamX.Bach Answer to add the name `cnt` after the BookingNumber fields

Comment: @Zeina thank you. Actually, we only need to name columns in `first SELECT query` of UNION ALL statement. The problem here is in SQL Server Subquery must has alias name, and OP had already fixed it.

Comment: Oh sure, I forgot about the union, yes we need to  name the first field... I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
SELECT (SELECT Count([fms].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER)
        FROM   [fms].[dbo].[Booking]
               .......
        WHERE  [fms].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02'
               AND [fms].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28') as fms_count,
       (SELECT Count([fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER)
        FROM   [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking] 
               .......
        WHERE  [fmsAir].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02'
               AND [fmsAir].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28') as fmsAir_count,
       (SELECT Count([fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].BOOKINGNUMBER)
        FROM   [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking]
               .....
        WHERE  [fmsProjects].[dbo].[Booking].RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02'
               AND [fmsProjects].[dbo].[File].ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28') as fmsProjects_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Who can read such a query?  Use table aliases!

```
SELECT COUNT(b.BOOKINGNUMBER) 
FROM [fms].[dbo].[Booking] b INNER JOIN
     [fms].[dbo].[Container] c
     ON b.[BOOKINGNUMBER] = c.[BOOKINGNUMBER] INNER JOIN
     [fms].[dbo].[File] f
     ON [c.FILENUMBER = f.FILENUMBER
WHERE b.RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [f.ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28';
```

As for getting these in one row, one method is just to use subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(b.BOOKINGNUMBER) 
        FROM [fms].[dbo].[Booking] b INNER JOIN
             [fms].[dbo].[Container] c
             ON b.[BOOKINGNUMBER] = c.[BOOKINGNUMBER] INNER JOIN
             [fms].[dbo].[File] f
             ON [c.FILENUMBER = f.FILENUMBER
        WHERE b.RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [f.ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
       ) as fms_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(b.BOOKINGNUMBER) 
        FROM [fmsair].[dbo].[Booking] b INNER JOIN
             [fmsair].[dbo].[Container] c
             ON b.[BOOKINGNUMBER] = c.[BOOKINGNUMBER] INNER JOIN
             [fmsair].[dbo].[File] f
             ON [c.FILENUMBER = f.FILENUMBER
        WHERE b.RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [f.ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
       ) as fmsair_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(b.BOOKINGNUMBER) 
        FROM [fmsprojects].[dbo].[Booking] b INNER JOIN
             [fmsprojects].[dbo].[Container] c
             ON b.[BOOKINGNUMBER] = c.[BOOKINGNUMBER] INNER JOIN
             [fmsprojects].[dbo].[File] f
             ON [c.FILENUMBER = f.FILENUMBER
        WHERE b.RELATIONCODE = 'SHIP02' AND [f.ETA BETWEEN '2000-10-27' AND '2016-10-28'
       ) as fmsprojects_count
```